# Paying the IRS money owed in Tax returns without an ITIN

Tags: united-states, taxes, non-resident, itin

- I am a non-resident alien
- I am filling the 1040NR-EZ
- Since it is my first US tax return, I do not have an ITIN. Hence, I am joining a W-7 to create an ITIN at the same time
- My tax return says that I owe money
- The wait time for an ITIN seems to be more than 6 weeks so I won't get it before the due date of my tax filing.
- I need to pay the money I owe before the due date but all payments require an ITIN or an SSN.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

When you file your taxes, you can give them a checking account to draw from. If you chose that way, they will draw the money, and all is fine.

Altenatively, you can send payment with your name and address and the ITIN 'applied for'. They should understand what that means, and apply it to your account. That is not recommendable if your name is very common, though.